# firewalld: forward traffic as a wireguard VPN gateway

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn, firewalld, gateway, wireguard

I have setup a pi running Pi OS 11 as a VPN gateway for my local network using Wireguard & Nftables, that all works fine.

However, I wish to switch over to firewalld to be compatible with docker without using iptables.

What I have so far is this:

- internal zone: eth0
- external zone: wg0

I cannot figure out how to get firewalld to forward traffic between eth0 & wg0. With raw nftables I just have the following, my forward chain drops by default:

```
nft insert rule inet firewall forward iifname "eth0" oifname "wg0" accept
nft insert rule inet firewall forward iifname "wg0" oifname "eth0" ct state related,established accept
```

But I cannot find out how to conditionally forward between interfaces, as the above rules.

I do not want eth0 in the external zone with wg0 as I want internet access kill-switched if the VPN goes down, plus it sort of goes against the whole idea of zones no? eth0 is just for the LAN & wg0 is for external connectivity.

Comment: Seems to me that what you would want is not "forwarding" of traffic between interfaces, but rather **routing** your Internet traffic to the VPN gateway. You could even configure a **static route**, so that if the VPN goes down, Internet access goes down as well, which effectively is the kill switch.

Comment: Wireguard puts those routes in, however the firewalld is dropping all forwarded packets from eth0 to wg0 & vice versa, so they never make it.